# Do I require a Thread Lock object?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hey, I am in the process of refactoring a program that requires some amount of threading. However, I do not have much prior experience with threading, so here's a (i'm guessing) simple question I need help with.

The program watches certain files (each watcher runs on a different thread), and when a change is detected, it calls a method call `Notify()`. `Notify()` method simply sends an email.

In case two or more threads detect a change at the same time, and call `Notify()` at the same time, will that be a problem?

I'm guessing that since `Notify()` isn't accessing any file that can't be opened multiple times or any such thing, there shouldn't be a problem `Notify()` is called by multiple threads at the same time. But I could be wrong.

And if I am wrong, is the best method to create an object and use `Lock(object)` before the call to `Notify()`?

Comment: If they are both using the same object to send the email, you'll probably need to lock (depends on whether the mail sending object guarantees thread safety of multiple send operations).  If they have separate objects and those can work independently (they don't internally rely on some shared state to perform the sending operation), you don't need to lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking is required if multiple threads need to access **shared state** (static or non-static) and *some of them trying to change*. If all they are doing is to *read*, it is *safe* for them to access it. Also if you do not have a shared state then it is fine.

Comment: Just what I thought. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Upon further inspection of the code, I realized sending of emails are being logged to a text file. Guess I will have have to lock

Comment: Yes, that has to be done in the class doing opening, writing and closing of the file. If you use NLog or Log4Net, they are already thread safe.

Comment: oh, ok. I am using NLog. Wasn't aware its threadsafe. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If notify method uses a shared resource (like a static variable which is being used by Notify() method) you may have some threading problems and locking might be necessary, if not, there will be no problems.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would need to do any locking is if there are variables inside `Notify()` that might be changed by multiple instances of `Notify()` running at the same time.

So let's say you have a `List<>` of files that have been detected (say, to prevent re-notification), and your `Notify()` method adds the file it detects to that `List<>`.  Multiple instances of `Notify()` might attempt to access that list at the same time, in which case you would consider locking (or otherwise synchronizing) that `List<>`.

From what you've described though, I don't think you need to worry about it.